# How can I get keywords within the site using Python3 and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I managed to get the title and description of the site using selenium. But I don't know how to get keywords within the site. Thank you for your answers

Comment: I found the solution, it might be useful.
examples of getting some tags
- link.get_attribute("href")
- driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.g') -> selenium web driver
- driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pnnext"]') -> selenium web driver